# What is HUD VIEW?

Tags: iphone

What is HUD View and how we can used in iPhone sdk or
 i want to use in UIMagePickerController?

Answer (score 9):

I'm assuming you mean HUD as 'Heads-up Display'.  This is where information is displayed on a screen as an overlay so the user can still see their 'normal' view.  Originally used in jet fighters to display speed/bearing information on the cockpit window so pilots could see the instrument data without having to take their eyes away from looking where they're going.

Not sure how to implement this on iPhone, I'm afraid, but assume it would involve writing text/graphics to a layer with a transparent background.

Answer (score 6):

I assume you mean the [UIProgressHUD](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/UIProgressHUD).

http://www.drobnik.com/touch/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/UIProgressHUD.png

You can't use it in the SDK because it's not documented. But there's alternatives such as [MBProgressHUD](http://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD).